# java common function for duplicate code

Tags: java

```
 public UMRResultObject insertDocumentation(UMRDocumentationDTO documentationDTO)
{
    Session     session = UMRHibernateUtil.getUmrSession();
    Transaction tx      = null;
    List<UMRDTO> duplicateDocumentationList=null;

    String objectType =documentationDTO.getId().getObjectType();
    String objectName =documentationDTO.getId().getObjectName();

    try
    {        
        duplicateDocumentationList = dao.getFilteredDocumentationList(objectType, objectName, false, session);

        if(duplicateDocumentationList.isEmpty())
        {
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            dao.insertDocumentation(documentationDTO, session);           
            tx.commit();
            ro.setSuccess(true);
            ro.getMessages().add("Record Inserted Successfully");
            if (ro.isSuccess())
            {
                if("Domain".equals(objectType))
                {
                    MMTUtil.getDomainDocumentationMap().put(objectName, documentationDTO.getDocumentationLink());
                }
                else  if("DomainCombo".equals(objectType))
                {
                    MMTUtil.getDomainDocumentationMap().put(objectName, documentationDTO.getDocumentationLink());
                }
                return ro;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ro.getMessages().add("Documentation for '" + objectName + "' " 
                            + objectType+ " already exists! \n");

            logger.info("Documentation for '" + objectName + "' " 
                            + objectType+ " already exists! \n");
        }
     }        

    return ro;
}

public UMRResultObject updateDocumentation(UMRDocumentationDTO documentationDTO)
{
    Session     session = UMRHibernateUtil.getUmrSession();
    Transaction tx      = null;

    try
    {
        String objectType = documentationDTO.getId().getObjectType();
        if("Domain".equals(objectType))
        {
            MMTUtil.getDomainDocumentationMap().put(documentationDTO.getId().getObjectName(), documentationDTO.getDocumentationLink());
        }
        else  if("DomainCombo".equals(objectType))
        {
            MMTUtil.getDomainDocumentationMap().put(documentationDTO.getId().getObjectName(), documentationDTO.getDocumentationLink());
        }

        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        dao.updateDocumentation(documentationDTO, session);
        tx.commit();
        ro.setSuccess(true);
        ro.getMessages().add("Record Updated Successfully");
        if(ro.isSuccess())
        {
             if("Domain".equals(objectType))
            {
                MMTUtil.getDomainDocumentationMap().put(objectName, documentationDTO.getDocumentationLink());
            }
            else  if("DomainCombo".equals(objectType))
            {
                MMTUtil.getDomainDocumentationMap().put(objectName, documentationDTO.getDocumentationLink());
            }
            return ro;
        }
    }
```

I dont want to ducplicate the code in if(ro.isSuccess()) and want to refactor the code but unable to get any further from this

I tried making another method for it unable to use documentationDTO what should I do

Comment: What was the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
if(ro.isSuccess()){
    populateMap(objectType, objectName, documentationDTO);
    return ro;
}
```

Method would be like below:

```
private void populateMap(String objectType, String objectName, UMRDocumentationDTO documentationDTO){
      if("Domain".equals(objectType) || "DomainCombo".equals(objectType))
      {
          MMTUtil.getDomainDocumentationMap().put(objectName, documentationDTO.getDocumentationLink());
      }
}
```

Comment: Do you think maybe you could remove the repeated code in this method?

Comment: Nice find. They both are essentially same code in both in `if` and `else if` blocks. Edited the answer to improve.